# How to programmatically restart the app in NativeScript?

Tags: nativescript

I am making some changes in my NativeScript app in real time, but to have the changes reflected I have to quit and restart the app.

Is there any way I can programmatically restart/close the app? Or any other ideas?

(much like Microsoft 'Teams' app does on Theme change)
[image]

Image source: https://www.howtogeek.com/719649/how-to-enable-dark-mode-in-microsoft-teams/

Answer (score 0):

May be if you give us more details, we can help you with another alternative.
Because, you can clear your application settings and return to the home page.
For example :
Nativescript + Angular :

```
import { clear } from "tns-core-modules/application-settings";


logOut() {
    clear(); \\ clearing all settings (User data, params, etc)
    this.router.navigate(["FirstPage"]); \\ restarting the navigation
  }
```

- [Application settings](https://v6.docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/application-settings)
- [Routing in Nativescript](https://v6.docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/angular-navigation.html)

Hope it will be useful for you,